# How to allow a single line break in regex?

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

I match the text between two tags as

```
/open(.*?)end/
```

How can I allow one single line break (`\n`) between two tags? If I use `s` modifier, all line breaks are allowed.

Comment: Try using `[\n]` for the newline character

Comment: @alfasin it's not HTML. They are different tags :)

Comment: You may try `open.*?\R?.*?end`. This allows only one linebreak in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~open(?:(?!open|end).)*(?:\R.*?)?end~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G2MXVm/2)

**Details**

- `open` - starting substring
- `(?:(?!open|end).)*` -  a tempered greedy token matching any char other than a line break char that is not a starting char of an `end` or `start` substring, as many as possible
- `(?:\R.*?)?` - an optional sequence of a line break followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `end` - trailing substring.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/open([^\n\r]*\R?[^\n\r]*)end/
```

where

- `[^\n\r]*` means 0 or more nor a line break
- `\R?` means 0 or 1 any kind of line break

Comment: 1) Why use `[^\n\r]` if `.` is meant to do that? 2) If there is `open text end\nsome text end` string, shouldn't the `open text end` be matched rather than [the whole string](https://regex101.com/r/4cwXSV/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: 1) Why not? because it means the same unless we have `(?s)` 2) You're right, I didn't take care of multiple `open...end`.